# Having a JavaScript function wait on the results of a Jquery dialog modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have function1 which needs the results of function2 before it can continue.

But  function2 gets what it needs by triggering a Jquery dialog window to open, and prompting the user to select one of two buttons.

The selection of the two buttons then causes function2 to do its work and pass that along to function1.

How do I get the value that the buttons give when selected in the dialog window back to function2.

See code below.

```
$('#choice-dialog').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: false,
   height:140,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
      "Proceed": function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         true //the value to be sent to function2;
      },
      Cancel: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         false //the value to be sent to function2;
      }
   }
});

function function1(){
   if(function2(variable)===true){
      return true
   }
}

var function2 = function(variable){
   if(idIsUsed){
      $("#choice-dialog").dialog("open");
      return **choice made by user via dialog**;
   }else{
      return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way. It is better to restructure your code such that the dialog callbacks call another function with `true` or `false`:

```
$('#choice-dialog').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: false,
   height:140,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
      "Proceed": function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         otherFunction(true);
      },
      Cancel: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         otherFunction(false);
      }
   }
});

var function2 = function(variable){
   if(idIsUsed){
      $j("#choice-dialog").dialog("open"); 
   } else {
      otherFunction(true);
   }
}
```